# Angular 6 : action after radio choice

Tags: angular, radio-button

I'm pretty with Angular 6 and I'm struggling in showing a div depending which radio is clicked by the user

this my radio form:

```
    <form>
         <input type="radio" name="job" [(ngModel)]="model.job" value="manager">Manager
         <input type="radio" name="job" [(ngModel)]="model.job" value="employee" ng-change='jobDisplay()'>Employee
<div *ngIf="display" >TEST</div>
    </form>
```

Here is my Typescript file

display = false;

```
jobDisplay() {
    this.display = true;
  }
```

It seems that jobDisplay is never called.

I also tried to change

```
<input type="radio" name="job" [(ngModel)]="model.job" value="employee" [checked]='display'>Employee
```

I want the word test to be displayed when I click on the second one. What could I do?

Answer (score 2):

Just set `model.job='employee'`

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="job" [(ngModel)]="model.job" value="manager">Manager
  <input type="radio" name="job" [(ngModel)]="model.job" value="employee">Employee
  <div *ngIf="model.job=='employee'" >TEST</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Issue 1 : You are using ng-change which is wrong, it is the AngularJS syntax. It will not work in Angular 2+
>
> Issue 2: You don't need to use any function since you are using `ngModel`.

### html

```
    <form>
         <input type="radio" name="job" [(ngModel)]="model.job" value="manager">Manager
         <input type="radio" name="job" [(ngModel)]="model.job" value="employee">Employee

       <div *ngIf="model.job == 'employee'" >Employee</div>
       <div *ngIf="model.job == 'manager'" >Manager</div>

    </form>
```

> Note : Its looks like you very new to the Angular. Better would be if you go through some tutorial before experiment.

This may help you out - https://angular.io/tutorial